# Alternating Current/Electromototive Force equaling 0?

Tags: electromagnetism

All alternating current diagrams are drawn as sinusoidal waves that intercept with x axis. Given our usual sine wave that equals to 0 at 180° it would mean the alternating current would equal to 0. If we are generating alternating current by creating electromototive force with Faraday's law of induction, a change in magnetic flux is needed. If we use a wire plate spinning at 'w' constant angular speed and send magnetic field lines through it we get our emf and alternating current. However, I can't understand how alternating current can equal to 0 since if the wire plate is contantly spinning there would always be a 'rate of change' in magnetic flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a "wire plate" different from a wire loop in some way?

If you envision a circular wire loop of area $A$ spinning with a diameter of the loop along the $\hat{z}$ direction as the axis of rotation, with a constant magnetic field $\vec{B}$ in the $\hat{y}$ direction, and we take the normal vector to the loop of wire $\vec{n}$, where $\vec{n} = cos(\omega t)\ \hat{x} + sin(\omega t)\ \hat{y}$, then the magnetic flux $\Phi$ is given by

$$\Phi = \vec{B} \cdot A\ \vec{n}$$
$$\Phi = A\ B\ \hat{y} \cdot (cos(\omega t)\ \hat{x} + sin(\omega t)\ \hat{y})$$
$$\Phi = A\ B\ sin(\omega t)$$

Then using Faraday's law, the emf $\epsilon$ is

$$\epsilon = - A\ B\ \omega\ cos(\omega t)$$

Which is indeed zero twice per rotation.

Intuitively, you need only think about when the flux is changing the fastest or slowest.  The flux is changing the fastest when the flux is zero (the loop is facing perpendicular to the field).  The flux is changing slowest when the loop is facing the field or facing away, and in fact at those two moments the flux momentarily stops changing; the emf drops to zero.  It's similar to the way that when you throw a ball straight up, the ball's position momentarily stops changing right at the top of the trajectory.

It might help to consider that when the loop is facing directly away from the magnetic field (the point when the flux is greatest), the flux goes form "almost highest flux" to "highest flux" to "almost highest flux".  Since the flux goes up, then down, it must instantaneously stop changing.  That's the point when the rate of change of the flux is zero.

Comment: With the ball example given I can understand a bit better. I will try to discuss that with my friend who actually asked me the question. Oh and yes I mean the wire loop. I am not having physics lessons in English so I sometimes can't find exact terms for some things.